built-in Spring Security authorization form
I am doing registration and user login on the site in java, Spring Security, Spring boot and the problem arose is that when I log in to localhost:8080/login, the standard form from Spring Security opens, and not the one I wrote, here is the SecurityConfig code, if necessary, I will attach the code of other files
package com.Schat;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig
{
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain (HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers("/register", "/h2-console/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin(form -> form
                        .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                )
                .logout(logout -> logout
                        .permitAll()
                );

        http.headers(headers -> headers.frameOptions(frameOptions -> frameOptions.disable()));
        return http.build();
    }


    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder()
    {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}


This could really have many reasons and I wish you wrote more details.
But I guess the file does not exist in the src/main/resources/templates path or spring security does not find it.
My suggestion is to write the following code:
.formLogin(form -> form
        .loginPage("/login")
        .loginProcessingUrl("/you_login_apth")
        .permitAll()
)

I mean try explicitly setting loginProcessingUrl
